# I want to create multi tenancy in pentaho BI?

Tags: java, pentaho, pentaho-data-integration, pentaho-report-designer

how to create multi tenancy in pentaho ? 
How to attached the tenant Id in pentaho session?
is there any setting to enable the multi tenancy in pentaho?

Answer (score 1):

They are called slave servers in PDI.

Install a carte on a server (which means run the `carte.sh` with `ip/host+port` on your linux and let it run). Then look for the `Slave Server` menu in the `left-panel View` (you are probably in `Design` mode) and create a `New` carte. The Web AppName is blanc (unless you have an EE-licence), and the username/password is cluster/cluster (unless you changed the carte-config.xml as explained in the doc).

Then when you run a job you can select if you want to run it on your machine or on a distant server, and this can be done for each sub-jobs of a job. The 
status of the job can be followed by typing host:port/kettle/status in your browser. And it is not hard to run jobs in parallel from within a job (`right-click`).

As far as tenantId is concerned, there is. It is called the channel and you need it to read the log files. Buit it is another story.

Relevant doc:

- [Carte documentation](http://wiki.pentaho.com/display/EAI/Carte+User+Documentation)
- [Defining a slave server in spoon](https://help.pentaho.com/Documentation/5.1/0L0/0Y0/060/000)
- [Available web service](https://help.pentaho.com/Documentation/7.1/0R0/070/020/020)